# BoundingBox different in Python/MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scikit-image

In MATLAB I have the following code:

```
props = regionprops(bw,'BoundingBox');
v = cat(1, props.BoundingBox);
```

and v returns this: [194.5000,  156.5000,  378.0000,  154.0000;
325.5000,  342.5000,  160.0000,  160.0000]

In Python:

```
label_img = label(bw, connectivity = bw.ndim)
regions = regionprops(label_img)
v = np.array([p.bbox for p in regions]).reshape(2,4)
```

and this time v returns: array([[156, 194, 310, 572],
[342, 325, 502, 485]])

Some numbers are similar but I don't know what they really mean. ¿Does anyone knows how can I get the same result in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output formats for both of these are a bit different and I presume the very same might be confusing you

OpenCV output:

```
[156, 194, 310, 572] -> [min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y]
```

Matlab output:

```
[194.5000, 156.5000, 378.0000, 154.0000] -> [min_y, min_x, height, width]
```

If you want to replicate the values, it is simply the matter of adding up the height and width parameters in the matlab output

*Please note: I might have mixed up the 2 axes. But the basic concept of addition remains the same regardless*

Comment: I realized that, while MATLAB gives you the third and fourth columns as the width and height, python gives you min_col and max_col, and the first 2 are changed in position. Thanks anyways!

Comment: But this doesn’t explain where that half pixel comes from.